# Naive bayes example by hand

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, naive-bayes, conditional-independence

Given the following data

```
        X1   X2.O      X2.Y     out
-------------------------------------
        0      1        0      0
        0      0        1      0
        1      1        0      0
        1      0        0      0
        1      1        0      0
-------------------------------------
        0      1        0      1
        1      0        0      1
        0      1        0      1
        1      0        0      1
        1      0        1      1
=====================================
Prob   0.6    0.5      0.2    0.5
P(S)   0.6    0.4      0.2    
P(-S)  0.6    0.6      0.2 
=====================================
```

There are two categorical variables, $x_1, x_2$ where $x_1$ has two levels and $x_2$
has three (`x2 \in O, M, Y`).

I would like to compute the result of naive bayes by hand to find the
probability of success given `x1 = 0` and `x2.O = 0`

I know that i have conditional independence, meaning

$$
P(A,B \vert C) = P(A \vert C) P(B \vert C)
$$

I'm not sure how to calculate for this though.

## edit

Here is what I've tried

I'm interested in $P(C | A, B)$ which can be written using bayes theorem as

$$
P(C | A,B) = \frac{ P(A,B | C) P(C)}{P(A,B)}
$$

using conditional independence the numerator of this is

$$
P(A,B |C)P(C) = 
P(A | C)P(B | C) P(C)
$$

and the denominator is

$$
P(A,B) = P(A,B | C)P(C) + P(A,B | ¬C)P(¬C)
$$

which can be expressed as

$$
P(A,B | C)P(C) + P(A,B | ¬C)P(¬C)
= 
P(A | C)P(B | C)P(C) + P(A | ¬C)P(B | ¬C)P(¬C)
$$

giving the expression

$$
\frac{ P(A,B | C) P(C)}{P(A,B)}
= 
\frac{ 
P(A | C)P(B | C) P(C)
  }{
P(A | C)P(B | C)P(C) + P(A | ¬C)P(B | ¬C)P(¬C)}
$$

From the above table these are , using `A = x1` and `B= x2.O`

$P(A|C) = 3/5 = 0.6$

$P(B|C) = 2/5 = 0.4$

$P(C) = 0.5$

$P(A|¬C) = 3/5 = 0.6$

$P(B|¬C) = 3/5 = 0.6$

$P(¬C) = 0.5$

giving

$$
\frac{
(0.6)(0.4)(0.5)
}{
  (0.6)(0.4)(0.5) + (0.6)(0.6)(0.5)
}
$$

Which is $0.4285$

## edit 2

Is the above example a demonstration of the assumption naive bayes makes. In
that there is no data in the sample set that has `x1` and `x2.O` being true when
`out=1`, yet we still get a probability of `~ 0.43`.

Comment: @Tim i've edited the post with some working, thanks

Comment: Unless I missed something, you seem to have solved it?

Comment: @Tim perhaps... I managed to convince myself that something was incorrect about my approach, so perhaps I've been trying to find an invisible error I'm not sure.

Comment: @Tim what i would be interested in is whether this example demonstrates the conditional independence assumption is quite a stretch - basing this on there being no instances within the data of `x2.O` and `x1` both being true, yet we still find a probability of ~ 0.43